# Working around with observable and subscriptions

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I am using Angular6, below is my scenario:

I am trying to pass information between Component1 and COmponent2 via a service. I see that service receives message from Component1, but Component2 doesnt receive the passed message.

In Page1:

//when a mouse move in a particular area happens, this method is called

```
actionMove: function(evt,obj) {  
    var messService = new MessService();
    messService.sendMessage('Sending message from Component1 to Component2!'); 
}
```

inMessService file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) { 

        console.log("*** service got message from component 1 ***");
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {  // this communicates with component2
        console.log("*** component 2 trying to get message ***");
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In Component2:

```
constructor(private messService: MessService) { 
    // subscribe to message service method  
    this.subscription = this.messService.getMessage()
        .subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
```

Could you please help me understand what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you create a new MessService in the function in component 1 and don't use `constructor(private messService: MessService)`?

Comment: my component 1 structure is as follows:

export class ComponentTemplate {

create(){
//...........
........//
actionMove: function(evt,obj) {  
    var messService = new MessService();
    messService.sendMessage('Sending message from Component1 to Component2!'); 
}
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fridoo's comment goes to the heart of it --

to use a service in multiple components you need to take advantage of angular's dependency injection.  you want to reference your service class in the constructor like in your component2 in component1, this way both components are using the same MessService.

you can just create an empty constructor like

```
constructor(private messService: MessService) {}
```

to get the service injected -- have you tried doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Im not an Angular pro, but I think you using two different instances of MessService here because you new up one in actionMove in component1, and injecting an other one into component2, hence working with one does not reflect in the other.

Try to inject MessService into component1 also using constructor injection, as fridoo suggests. Because you provide your service in root, you'll get a singleton.

[Singleton services - Angular](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)